# How to troubleshoot an error message indicating that Elasticsearch client methods are not recognized in Go?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, go-olivere

I am trying to execute a search on the Elasticsearch client in Go ([olivere/elastic](https://github.com/olivere/elastic)), using the appropriate client library for Elasticsearch version 7.x. The expected behavior is to compile the code without errors and return a scrollable search result with the specified query, aggregation, size, track total hits, pretty, and sort options.

However, the actual behavior is producing an error message that suggests the methods Aggregation, Size, TrackTotalHits, Pretty, Sort, and Do are not recognized. This error message may indicate an issue with the syntax or reference of the Elasticsearch client methods.

Can anyone suggest steps to troubleshoot this issue and help me resolve the error? Additionally, please find below the code I am currently working with:

```golang
searchResult, err := r.elasticClient.
    Scroll().
    Index(r.index).
    Query(query).
    Aggregation("agg", agg).
    Size(limit).
    TrackTotalHits(true).
    Pretty(true).
    Sort("startTime", true).
    Do(context.Background())
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: 1. Please do not post images of text. 2. Ist this a question about your IDE or about an _actual_ compilation error?.

Comment: @Volker 1. I already put the text, what do you want from me? 2.) It is about actual compilation errors. Btw why are you focusing on the image instead of the question so much?

Comment: What is the actual error message? What would a minimal reproducable example look like? How do you import the library? What's the content of your go.mod? You will have to provide actionable data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll API is used to scroll through documents, not aggregations. The [ref](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/scroll-in-elasticsearch-aggregation/209885/2).